# i want to include a switch case in dynamic HTML block

Tags: javascript

I want to include a switch condition in this dynamic HTML block. How can I do that?

```
editQuestionBlockHTML=' <div class="addQuestionBlock" >'
      +'<div  class="selectQnLabel"><p class="selectQnLabel">Select a type of question</p>'
      +'<p class="questionTypes">';



       switch(questionType)
      {
      case "Radio":
      editQuestionBlockHTML += +' <select id="EditQuestionType" onchange="changeQuestionType();">'
             +' <option value="radioBtn" selected="selected">Radio Button</option>'

            +' <option value="checkBox">Check Box </option>'
            +'  <option value="pullDownMenu">Pull Down Menu</option>'
            +'  <option value="ratingScale"> Rating Scale</option>'
            +'  <option value="commentBox"> Comment Box</option>'
            +'  <option value="singleTextBox"> Single Text Box</option>'
            +' </select>';
      break;

       }

     editQuestionBlockHTML+=+'</p></div>'



      +'<div  style="float:left;width:100%;">'
      +' <p class="selectQnLabel">Enter Question</p>'
      +' <p><textarea "EditQuestionTitle-'+questionId+'" class="inputBox" rows="4" cols="65" >'+questionText+'</textarea></p>'
      +'<div style="clear:both;">'

       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'
      +'<div  style="float:left;width:100%;">'
      +' <p class="selectQnLabel">Enter Choices (Each choice on a separate line)</p>'
      +' <p><textarea id="editQuestionChoiceList-'+questionId+'" class="inputBox" rows="4" cols="65">'
      +choicelist
      +'</textarea></p>'
      +'<div style="clear:both;">'

       +'</div>'
      +'</div>'


      +'</div>' 
      +'</div>';
      return editQuestionBlockHTML;
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific , i mean i don't really understand what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Here's some documentation.

Comment: i know how switch case works. But i need to know how this can include in a dynamic HTML block

Answer (score 0):

The "switch" condition is very easy in javascript:

```
switch(n){
    case 1: // it's like: if(n == 1) ...
        /* do stuff */
    break; //really 'breaks' the switch and ignore everything else inside the switch
    case 2:
    case 3: //multiple matches ..it's like: else if(n == 2 || n == 3)
        /* do stuff */
    break;
    default: //default code if no match has been found with your cases .. it's like the last "else" in your if .. else statement
        /* do stuff */
}
```